# Cannot resolve type for template function

Tags: templates, d, phobos

I'm trying to code up something very simple in D, but I'm having a few problems with one of the standard library template functions (specifically, `nextPermutation` from `std.algorithm`).

The crux of what I'm trying to do is to create all permutations of pandigital numbers (that is, numbers including all the values 1 to 9 exactly once).

To do this, I've done the following:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.conv;

int[] pandigitals()
{
    char[] initial = "123456789".dup;
    auto pan = [to!int(initial)];
    while(nextPermutation!(initial)) {
       pan ~= to!int(initial);
    }
    return pan;
}
```

This gives me the error:

> Error: cannot resolve type for nextPermutation!(initial)

I've also tried to explicitly set the types:

```
while(nextPermutation!("a<b", char[])(initial))
```

However, this gives an error saying it cannot match the template:

> Error: template instance std.algorithm.nextPermutation!("a < b", char[]) does not match template declaration nextPermutation(alias less = "a < b", BidirectionalRange)(ref BidirectionalRange range) if (isBidirectionalRange!BidirectionalRange && hasSwappableElements!BidirectionalRange)

What is the correct form of the call meant to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your first problem is that you're passing `initial` as a template argument instead of a function argument. The `!()` is for template arguments. so, instead of

```
while(nextPermutation!(initial))
```

you need to do

```
while(nextPermutation(initial)) {
```

Now, that will still give you an error.

```
q.d(10): Error: template std.algorithm.nextPermutation cannot deduce function from argument types !()(char[]), candidates are:
/usr/include/D/phobos/std/algorithm.d(12351):        std.algorithm.nextPermutation(alias less = "a<b", BidirectionalRange)(ref BidirectionalRange range) if (isBidirectionalRange!BidirectionalRange && hasSwappableElements!BidirectionalRange)
```

And that's because `hasSwappableElements!(char[])` is `false`, and per `nextPermutations`' template constraint it needs to be `true` for a type to work with `nextPermutations`.

It's `false` because all strings are treated as ranges of `dchar` rather than their actual element type. This is because in UTF-8 (`char`) and UTF-16 (`wchar`), there are multiple code units per code point, so operating on individual code units could break up a code point, whereas in UTF-32 (`dchar`), there's always one code unit per code point. Essentially, if arrays of `char` or `wchar` were treated as ranges of `char` or `wchar`, you'd run a high risk of breaking up characters so that you'd end up with pieces of characters rather than whole characters. So, in general in D, if you want to operate on an individual character, you should use `dchar`, not `char` or `wchar`. If you're not very familiar with Unicode, I'd suggest reading [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spoelsky on the subject.

However, regardless of why `hasSwappableElements!(char[])` is `false`, it *is* `false`, so you're going to need to use a different type. The simplest thing would probably be to just swap your algorithm over to using `dchar[]` instead.

```
int[] pandigitals()
{
    dchar[] initial = "123456789"d.dup;
    auto pan = [to!int(initial)];
    while(nextPermutation(initial)) {
       pan ~= to!int(initial);
    }
    return pan;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a `static assert` in there for `isBidirectionalRange!(char[]);` but forgot about the `hasSwappableElements` constraint.